# Rendering to QWindow from another thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl

I have been trying to solve my problem for a while now and so far I didn't find a solution

I have a QT aplication, now I need to add a QWindow in it to draw with opengl.

I know that I need to call QWidget::createWindowContainer(), to create QWidget which I can insert into another widget, or mainwindow.
Now, I have created a context in the subclassed QWindow class that I have. I do this when the window gets exposed. Then I created another thread where my rendering class lives, passed the QOpenGLContext to it, make it current in there but no matter what I try it just doesn't work.

Subclass of QWindow I'm only initializing the context, nothing more (I have set the surface type in constructor):

```
void OpenGLWindow::initialize()
{
    if (!m_context) {
        m_context = new QOpenGLContext();
        m_context->setFormat(requestedFormat());
        m_context->create();
    }

    if(!isRunning) {
    thread = new ThreadHelper(m_context, this);
    thread->start();
    }
}
```

Then the ThreadHelper:

```
ThreadHelper::ThreadHelper(QOpenGLContext *context, OpenGLWindow *window) : 
m_window(window),
m_context(context)
{
}


void ThreadHelper::run()
{
    m_context->makeCurrent(m_window);

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5);

    // the rendering is done here, it's a loop, where I loop 
    // over classes and call the render method
}

void ThreadHelper::swapOpenGLBuffers(){
    m_context->swapBuffers(m_window);
}
```

It crashs at the m_context->makeCurrent(m_window) line.

Also tried moving the context to that another thread but with no succes, I got a runtime error which said that it cannot be moved.

Comment: Race conditions maybe?

Comment: I don't think so, but I don't know the internal details of QT. However from what I can tell, I don't do anything that could lead to race condition

Comment: For anyone reading this now, there is no need to move the context to the rendering thread, you avoid affinity issues and anything concerning locks later on. Create it there (in the rendering thread) since your surface is only concerned with painting, the only thing that should tie these classes is the `QWindow` passed and `swapBuffers(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation:

> QOpenGLContext can be moved to a different thread with moveToThread().
>   Do not call makeCurrent() from a different thread than the one to
>   which the QOpenGLContext object belongs. A context can only be current
>   in one thread and against one surface at a time, and a thread only has
>   one context current at a time.

So you need to call something like `m_context->moveToThread(thread)` before starting the thread. That possibly didn't work for you because you tried to call it in the other thread. `moveToThread` must be called in the thread that currently owns the object (i.e. the thread that created it).

Comment: I did it this way, and it works, well sort of. The problem is that I have to make 2 call of gl... to take effect, which is really strange.
I make the context current in the render thread (also the thread that owns the context) but when I call glClear*, the first time it gets totally ignored, only the second time it actually clears the screen and sets the color. I'm going to accept this solution and start another question about this different issue.